# No rows modified when updating records

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have 5 tab pages, with a `Datagridview` in each pages. Each tab represents a table in my database. The problem is, when updating, only the first table is being updated. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - employee

    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE employee SET [Last_Name] = @lname, [First_Name]= @fname, MI = @mi, Bday = @bday, Age = @age, [Nationality] = @natio, [Contact_Number] = @contact, Sex = @gender, Address = @address, Department = @department, [Position] = @position, TIN = @tin, SSS = @sss, Pagibig = @pagibig, PhilHealth = @phh, Termi_Resi = @termiresi, [Date_hired] = @datehired, [Rate_Month] = @rm, [Date_End] = @dateTermiResi, Status = @status, [Father_Name] = @father, [Mother_Name] = @mother, Civil = @civil, Spouse = @spouse, [Number_of_Children] = @numberchild, Child1 = @child1, Child2 = @child2, Child3 = @child3, Child4 = @child4, Child5 = @child5, Child6 = @child6, Child7 = @child7, Child8 = @child8, Child9 = @child9 WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp", conn)
            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@lname", lname.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@fname", fname.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@mi", mi.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@bday", bday.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@age", age.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@natio", natio.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@contact", contact.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@gender", gender.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@address", address.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@department", department.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@position", position.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tim", tin.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@sss", sss.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@pagibig", pagibig.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@phh", phh.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@termiresi", termiresi.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@datehired", datehired.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@rm", rm.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dateTermiResi", dateTermiResi.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@status", status.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@father", father.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@mother", mother.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@civil", civil.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@spouse", spouse.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@numberchild", numberchild.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child1", child1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child2", child2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child3", child3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child4", child4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child5", child5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child6", child6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child7", child7.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child8", child8.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@child9", child9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp", numberemp.Text)
            End With
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            clearall()


        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - education

    Try
        Using conn2 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn2.Open()
            Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE education SET Level_Educ = @hlevelEduc, Degree = @degree, Post_Degree = @postdegree, Elem = @elem, Year_one = @year1, Highschool = @highschool, Year_two = @year2, College = @college, Year_three = @year3, Training_School = @trainingS, Year_four = @year4, Other_Educ = @otherEduc WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp1", conn2)
            numberemp1.Text = numberemp.Text
            With command2.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@hlevelEduc", hlevelEduc.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@elem", elem.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@year1", year1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@highschool", highschool.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@year2", year2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@college", college.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@year3", year3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@degree", degree.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@postdegree", postdegree.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@trainingS", trainingS.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@year4", year4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@otherEduc", otherEduc.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp1", numberemp1.Text)
            End With
            Dim rows = command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If rows = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows modified")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
            command2.Dispose()
            conn2.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - employment

    Try

        Using conn3 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn3.Open()
            Dim command3 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE employment SET Cname1 = @cname1, Posi1 = @posi1, Dept1 = @dept1, Tm1 = @tm1, Reason1 = @reason1, Cname2 = @cname2, Posi2 = @posi2, Dept2 = @dept2, Tm2 = @tm2, Reason2 = @reason2, Cname3 = @cname3, Posi3 = @posi3, Dept3 = @dept3, Tm3 = @tm3, Reason3 = @reason3, Cname4 = @cname4, Posi4 = @posi4, Dept4 = @dept4, Tm4 = @tm4, Reason4 = @reason4, Cname5 = @cname5, Posi5 = @posi5, Dept5 = @dept5, Tm5 = @tm5, Reason5 = @reason5, Cname6 = @cname6, Posi6 = @posi6, Dept6 = @dept6, Tm6 = @tm6, Reason6 = @reason6 WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp2", conn3)
            numberemp2.Text = numberemp.Text
            With command3.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@cname1", cname1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi1", posi1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept1", dept1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm1", tm1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason1", reason1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@cname2", cname2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi2", posi2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept2", dept2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm2", tm2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason2", reason2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@cname3", cname3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi3", posi3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept3", dept3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm3", tm3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason3", reason3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@cname4", cname4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi4", posi4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept4", dept4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm4", tm4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason4", reason4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@cname5", cname5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi5", posi5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept5", dept5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm5", tm5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason5", reason5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@cname6", cname6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@posi6", posi6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dept6", dept6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@tm6", tm6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@reason6", reason6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp2", numberemp2.Text)
            End With
             Dim rows = command3.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If rows = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows modified")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
            command3.Dispose()
            conn3.Close()
            clearall()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - disciplinary

    Try

        Using conn4 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn4.Open()
            Dim command4 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE disciplinary SET Offense1 = @o1, Action1 = @ao1, Dateoff1 = @do1, Offense2 = @o2, Action2 = @ao2, Dateoff2 = @do2, Offense3 = @o3, Action3 = @ao3, Dateoff3 = @do3, Offense4 = @o4, Action4 = @ao4, Dateoff4 = @do4, Offense5 = @o5, Action5 = @ao5, Dateoff5 = @do5, Offense6 = @o6, Action6 = @ao6, Dateoff6 = @do6, Offense7 = @o7, Action7 = @ao7, Dateoff7 = @do7, Offense8 = @o8, Action8 = @ao8, Dateoff8 = @do8, Offense9 = @o9, Action9 = @ao9, Dateoff9 = @do9, Offense10 = @10, Action10 = @ao10, Dateoff10 = @do10 WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp3 ", conn4)
            numberemp3.Text = numberemp.Text
            With command4.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@o1", o1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao1", ao1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do1", do1.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o2", o2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao2", ao2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do2", do2.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o3", o3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("ao3", ao3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do3", do3.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o4", o4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao4", ao4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do4", do4.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o5", o5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao5", ao5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do5", do5.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o6", o6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao6", ao6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do6", do6.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o7", o7.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao7", ao7.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do7", do7.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o8", o8.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao8", ao8.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do8", do8.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o9", o9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao9", ao9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do9", do9.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@o10", o10.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ao10", ao10.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@do10", do10.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp3", numberemp3.Text)
            End With
             Dim rows = command4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If rows = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows modified")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
            conn4.Close()
            clearall()

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    '/// UPDATING TABLE - trainings


    Try

        Using conn5 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
            conn5.Open()
            Dim command5 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE trainings SET ts1 = @ts1, dts1 = @dts1, ts2 = @ts2, dts2 = @dts2, ts3 = @ts3, dts3 = @dts3, ts4 = @ts4, dts4 = @dts4, ts5 = @ts5, dts5 = @dts5, ts6 = @ts6, dts6 = @dts6, ts7 = @ts7, dts7 = @dts7, ts8 = @ts8, dts8 = @dts8, ts9 = @ts9, dts9 = @dts9, ts10 = @ts10, dts10 = @dts10, ts11 = @ts11, dts11 = @dts11, ts12 = @ts12, dts12 = @dts12, ts13 = @ts13, dts13 = @dts13, ts14 = @ts14, dts14 = @dts14, ts15 = @ts15, dts15 = @dts15, ts16 = @ts16, dts16 = @dts16, ts17 = @ts17, dts17 = @dts17, ts18 = @ts18, dts18 = @dts18, ts19 = @ts19, dts19 = @dts19, ts20 = @ts20, dts20 = @dts20, ts21 = @ts21, dts21 = @dts21, ts22 = @ts22, dts22 = @dts22, ts23 = @ts23, dts23 = @dts23, ts24 = @ts24, dts24 = @dts24 WHERE [EmployID] = @numberemp4 ", conn5)
            numberemp4.Text = numberemp.Text
            With command5.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@ts1", ts1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts1", dts1.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts2", ts2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts2", dts2.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts3", ts3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts3", dts3.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts4", ts4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts4", dts4.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts5", ts5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts5", dts5.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts6", ts6.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts6", dts6.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts7", ts7.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts7", dts7.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts8", ts8.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts8", dts8.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts9", ts9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts9", dts9.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts10", ts10.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts10", dts10.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts11", ts11.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts11", dts11.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts12", ts12.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts12", dts12.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts13", ts13.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts13", dts13.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts14", ts14.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts14", dts14.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts15", ts15.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts15", dts15.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts16", ts16.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts16", dts16.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts17", ts17.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts17", dts17.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts18", ts18.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts18", dts18.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts19", ts19.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts19", dts19.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts20", ts20.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts20", dts20.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts21", ts21.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts21", dts21.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts22", ts22.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts22", dts22.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts23", ts23.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts23", dts23.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@ts24", ts24.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@dts24", dts24.Value)
                .AddWithValue("@numberemp4", numberemp4.Text)
            End With
             Dim rows = command5.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If rows = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows modified")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
            command5.Dispose()
            conn5.Close()
            disableall()
            clearall()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    Add1.Visible = True
    btnReg.Visible = True
    updateBtn.Visible = False
    RefreshDGV()
End Sub
```

I always get

> No rows modified

when updating the second up to the fifth table.

Here's my form to make it clear if it is too confusing..

[image]

Comment: Why don't you populate all datagridviews at the same time?

Comment: I did now, sir. Now my problem is updating. Since I didn't join my tables in one datagridview, I'm now facing a hard time fixing the update command since it shows "No row is modified." when updating the second up to the fifth table.

Comment: Why would it be difficult? You are just updating. Post a question. I'll check the details.

Comment: I'll edit my post sir. Wait.

Comment: Maybe no records are matching with the IDs in your `WHERE` condition?

Comment: I checked the database and there are iDs recorded in every table. Maybe I'll try to not to update all my table in one `Button`. Should I separate the update command? I mean, I'll put a `Button` in every tabpages..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124250/discussion-between-crush-sundae-and-wwwmarvscom).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to load data to tab pages when needed:

1. Use the Load event to load data for Tap Page 1
2. hook up to event Selecting of TabControl to load data for the other pages

   private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
       if (e.TabPage.Name == "TabPage1") {
           //Load Data for Tab page 1

   ```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Load(reader);
       grid2.DataSource = dt;
   }
   ```

   }